# Getting images from a random URL, facebook shareish

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

When you share a link on Facebook, it scans the page and lets you pick a thumbnail from that URL.

I want to do the same, and I imagine doing it using `JQuery`. How do I get my hands on those images using `JQuery`? It seems using $.ajax won't work because the images aren't hosted on my site.

Comment: This is easy, you don't! You can and should only access content from external sites on the serverside with a serverside languange and a proper DOM parser.

Comment: So I have to grab the URL a user pastes, throw it to using Ajax to the server responding with a JSON array of image URLs?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: Would that be a proper way to do it?

Comment: The ins and outs of how you get the images and pass them to the browser is up to you, but javascript has a same origin policy and can't access external sites (with some exceptions), and for this a serverside solution is definitively the way to go.